# Dovecot: List shared folder users using shared folder email address

Tags: dovecot

I know that I can list shared folder users using folder name

`doveadm acl get -A "Public/TestFolder"`

but is it possible to list shared folder users using shared folder email address `<shared>` used for adding user `<user>` to a shared folder from adding command like:

```
dovadm acl add -u <shared> INBOX user=<user>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. You're talking about listing while you use the `add` command, you talk about mail addresses where I don't see any. Some punctuation marks might also help at clarifying the issue.

Comment: @JensErat OP rephrased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that

`doveadm acl get -u <shared> INBOX`

do the job.